# How to intercept all requests going out from my Linux device?

Tags: python, linux, http, request

I have a python script, and I would like to see what requests it is making when I run it. Is there a Linux command that I can use to see all the http requests going out from my device? I need to be able to see the method, and the headers of the request. How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: tcpdump, tshark or wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcpdum or tcpflow.

For tcpdump you can use for port 80:

```
tcpdump -A -s 0 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

For tcpflow:

```
tcpflow -ce port 80
```

Check the docs please. I might be mistaking..